# Mysql Replicate, Master updates lock Slaves selects

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, replication

I have have a classifieds site with tons of traffic, have 1 master and 3 slaves.  Every slave is a web server and uses his localhost mysql for select queries and master for writes.  The app is developed in Rails 3.0.7 (Octopus for replicate) with MySQL 5.0.77 and I have a huge problem:

In moments of high traffic, the master replication (inserts, updates and deletes) locks completely the table that he is writing to.  This is normal, I know, but query takes like 15 seconds some times locking every select, and it hurts me bad.